# Check Python SQL Query result for variable

Tags: python, sql

I'm new to `Python` and working with `SQL queries`. I have a database that contains a table with meetings and their date along with an ID. What I want to do is check what meetings are happening on today's date. The code below results in showing all the meeting ID's that are happening on todays date. However I then want to check if a certain meeting ID is in the results, which I have stored as a variable, and if it is in there to carry out an IF function so I can then elaborate.

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM meeting WHERE DATE(starttime) = DATE(NOW())")

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to invest some time learning a library like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) if you're going to do a lot of work with databases. It'll save a lot of manual effort working with cursor objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask the database to tell you if the id is there:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM meeting WHERE DATE(starttime) = DATE(NOW()) AND id=%s", (id,))
if cur.rowcount:
    # The id is there
else:
    # The id is not there.
```

I am assuming that you are using MySQLdb here; different database adapters use slightly different query parameter styles. Others might use `?` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, that worked a treat! Sorry I was using MySQLdb,I should have mentioned. Really appreciate the help.